# Searching List of list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of list with:

```
[['1','Alex'],['2','Dwayne'],['3','George'],['4','Jake']]
```

and I'm using binary search to search the list of list and returning an output depending on the user input.

Basically, the user is required to key in the name represented by the second element in the individual list and return the first element.

```
userinput = Dwayne

output = 2
```

Here's my code:

```
lst = [['1','Alex'],['2','Dwayne'],['3','George'],['4','Jake']]

name = input("Enter name:")

def binarySearch(l,t):
    low = 0
    high = len(l)-1
    while low<= high:
       mid = (low+high)//2
       if l[mid][1] == t:
          return [mid][0]
       elif l[mid][1]>t:
          high = mid-1
       else:
          low = mid+1
    return -1

result = binarySearch(lst,name)
print(result)
```

Im getting 0 as the output which is not what i wanted so i need some tips on binary search. Normally, binary search for list with integers is alright but I'm unsure about strings.

Comment: I have the impression that 0 and 1 indices are swapped here. You're  comparing the names and returning the indices. Plus there's a typo `return [mid][0]` just returns `mid`, weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside this `if` statement:

```
if l[mid][1] == t:
          return [mid][0]
```

change `return [mid][0]` into `return l[mid][0]`, as you want to return the first entry in the element `l[mid]` in the list `l`.